# a-text component not support Arabic text

Tags: aframe

no support for Arabic text in `a-text` component, also all the  A-Frame’s built-in fonts doesn't support Arabic.

a-frame v: 0.6 , 
testing in Chrome ,
Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can either:
1. use a custom font, by pointing a url to the .fnt file ( and the .png font file) as described in the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/text.html).
 Its done by simply defining
`font:urlto.fntfile;fontImage:urlto.pngfile` in the text component or primitive.

2. As described in the docs, rendering 2D text is no easy task, so You could make a transparent image containing Your text in arabic.

(2) Seems to be simpler, but it's a pain when You need to change a typo, or sth in the text. I use it for Polish characters anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate a custom font from a fontset that contains Arabic characters. In WebGL, we don't get fonts for free, they are converted into glyphs and vertices.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/text.html#custom-fonts

Answer (score 0):

A more recent component `aframe-troika-text` provides a simpler solution that can render directly from a referenced font file.
https://github.com/lojjic/aframe-troika-text